# Google recaptcha not rendering properly

Tags: recaptcha

When I implemented google recaptcha for my site using the instructions given by Google everything works fine but the div itself renders a bit oddly:

[image: reCAPTCHA rendering]

I am using the standard DIV code recommended by Google:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-site-key" data-callback="enableBtn" data-expired-callback="disableBtn"></div>
```

I have tried to adjust the padding for the DIV but nothing seems to work. Has anyone else had this problem and solved it?

UPDATE: I tried with the most basic site possible, no css and I still get the same rendering.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-secret-site-key"></div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE 2. Works fine in Microsoft Edge. Seems to be a Firefox problem...

Comment: We can't tell what's wrong with your HTML without seeing the HTML.

Comment: Have added the code but there isn't much to look at. The div is rendered by the Google script.

Comment: I suspect there's something else in your page that is causing the problem. Create the smallest page of HTML that you can that still exhibits the problem, and show us that as the example.

Comment: @AndyLester - good idea. I tried this but it made no difference. I used a v basic page as per update above.